# Using an ActionListener in one class to start a timer in another class

Tags: java, swing, class, timer, actionlistener

I have a class (simulation) which creates an instance of another class (GUI). Inside the class GUI there is a button (start) which has an actionlistener attached to it.

I need this actionlistener to start a timer in simulation but I can't figure out how to do it.

Code in Class Simulation:

```
public class Simulation{

private static JFrame frame;
private static GUI control;
public static Integer xcontrol = 100, ycontrol = 100;

public Timer timer;
public int steps;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Simulation sim = new Simulation ();

}

public Simulation() {

frame = new JFrame("Action Listener Test");
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,0));

control = new GUI (xcontrol, ycontrol);
frame.getContentPane().add(control , BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setResizable(false);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
}


public void StartTimer() {
    timer.start();
    System.out.println("It worked!");   
}
```

Code in Class GUI:

```
        panel1.add(button1a);

            button1a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                    Simulation.StartTimer();
                    }
                } );
```

The error Eclipse tells me there is, is that for "Simulation.timer.start();" :

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method StartTimer() from the type Simulation.

However the method StartTimer() cannot be static as this seems to break the timer...

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: How the actionPerformed gets sim?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally posted part f the code incorrectly, the actionPerformed now reads:
Simulation.StartTimer();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `this` as an argument to the `GUI` constructor.

In general it is best to avoid such cyclic references. Both the `GUI` and `Simulator` become dependent upon one another. The essence of the solution is to separate out the GUI from the interesting domain-specific behaviour.

(BTW: I would strongly avoid using static variables for anything other than constants. Also avoid non-private instance variables. But point for not extending `JFrame`!)

There is some hideous boilerplate that you should add to prevent multithreading.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
                Simulation sim = new Simulation();
    }});
}
```

Comment: I apologise, I made a mistake in the code I posted. The "main constructor" was actually a "Simulation" instructor. As such sim is itself a "Simulation" object, so it couldn't be an argument for the GUI constructor I don't think...

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have your GUI class expose the button via a getButton() method, then after creating the GUI object, your Simulation class can add its own ActionListener to the button, e.g. control.getButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener()... etc.